# Can I travel to Switzerland from Pakistan?

Tags: visas, switzerland, refugees

I’m a Pakistan permanent resident and holder of a Pakistan refugee travel document. I’m planning to travel to Switzerland.

Answer (score 3):

You can, if you apply for and are granted a visa.  See https://www.sem.admin.ch/dam/sem/en/data/rechtsgrundlagen/weisungen/visa/bfm/bfm-anh01-liste2-e.pdf.download.pdf/bfm-anh01-liste2-e.pdf for more details:

> ## 2.4 Refugees
>
> As a general rule, the travel document for refugees issued in accordance with the London Agreement
> of 15 October 1946 or the Geneva Refugee Convention of 28 July 1951 allows entry into Switzerland
> (see Annex EU-10) to Visa Handbook I and the SEM Supplement).
>
> ### 2.4.1 Travel document for refugees issued by Switzerland
>
> The travel document for recognised refugees (blue) issued under the Geneva Convention of 28 July
> 1951 (passport valid for 5 years) entitles the holder to enter Switzerland without a visa.
>
> ### 2.4.2 Travel document for refugees issued by an EU member state, Norway, Iceland, Liechtenstein or the United Kingdom
>
> For a maximum stay of 90 days in any 180-day period, holders of such a document do not require a
> visa provided they are resident in the state that issues the travel document. Proof of residence can
> normally be provided in the form of a residence permit.
>
> ### 2.4.3 Travel document for refugees issued by another state
>
> Holders of such a document require a visa to enter Switzerland regardless of the nationality stated in the document.